# Leftover product attributes due to reindex failure

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, reindex

I have on my frontend catalog page some product attributes that are not existing eny more, but due to bad reindexing, they are still appearing in the catalog page as filters. How can I remove them? The reindexation process is funky and always clogs at some reindex (either Catalog flat data, or Catalog search index, or some other one), so I doubt it has to do with reindaxtion. Any idea on how to overcome this? There is always some reindaxtion process going on, if not one, then the other. How to clear indexes completely? I tried setting the max_execution_time to 3600 in Mage.php, and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried running indexes from the command line? `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` for M1 and `bin/magento indexer:reindex` in M2. Sometimes that'll work for me when the admin end keeps failing.

Comment: Thanks! It actually passed without ANY problems, BUT! In admin, there is still an out-of-the-blue automatic reindexing and it clogs again. The attributes are still persisting! - Even though I even switched off the module that activated them in the first place.

Comment: What's your version of Magento and what module were you using (that you switched off)?